# SqlBulkCopy hangs without any exception or timeout when inserting a datatable with even a single row

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

Having an issue, basically I have a very large datatable (50,000 rows) and I am using SqlBulkCopy to insert it via this function I wrote:

```
public static void DoSqlBulkCopy(string connectionString, string destinationTableName, DataTable dataTable, int batchSize = 2000)
{
    using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints))
    {
        bulk.BatchSize = batchSize;
        bulk.DestinationTableName = destinationTableName;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName, dataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
        }

        bulk.WriteToServer(dataTable);
    }
}
```

This code has worked for other stuff but on this dataset it just hangs on WriteToServer.

I scratched my chin for a bit and fired up the SQL profiler but there is no activity.

Any suggestions? It doesn't timeout either, I left it overnight.

Comment: How's it go without the columnmappings loop?

Comment: You can't catch statements in Profiler, when bulk copying. Did you try without batches? How did you find out that it hangs on Write? Do you have try-catch block? Can you reproduce this with 1 row in datatable?

Comment: Ah... so with 1 row the same issue occurs. Something must be blocking the database I guess, although strange that it doesn't time out. There's no try catch, just logging to console before and after that line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Spelt the table name wrong, was inserting into CuteCats instead of CuteCat. It hung with no error message. Blasted thing!

Comment: I would recommend taking your connection string and trying it on a non-sql bulk copy operation. Hopefully you'll get a useful error message.

Comment: If your SQLBulkCopy is hanging randomly, it is probably a threading issue. This happens a lot if you're using Entity Framework alongside it as it can conflict if you don't properly manage your connections. I'm afraid I don't have any other advice.